# Simple mechanics problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

I have no idea how to approach this problem I drew the diagram but that hasn't helped that much.

[image]

Comment: use the kinematical equations for uniform motion of objects and solve to find the times and space-interval at 1 mile apart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with (a).
The trains A and B are 1 mile apart.
The fly travels at 2 miles per minute, and train B is coming toward it at 1 mile per minute,
so train B sees the fly coming toward it at 3 miles per minute.
So it will take 1/3 of a minute to travel that mile.
(You see the trick here? By talking about the combined speed, we can treat train B as if it were standing still.)
Now you tell me how far the fly travels in that 1/3 of a minute.

Now (b).
You told me in (a) how far the fly traveled when going from A to B,
so it turns around, and that, minus the distance that A traveled in that time, is now the distance between it and A.
So how long will it take to reach A, and how far would it have flown in that time?

Now you take it the rest of the way...

Comment: Incidentally, for the last part (e), you compute how long it takes the two trains to hit each other. That is the time for which the fly was flying at 2 miles per minute. So although it seems to do an infinite number of turns, it takes a finite time and travels a finite distance. A common variation on Zeno's paradox.